# Files not showing up after mounting two folders with docker image

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am running a TensorFlow jupyter notebook container. I am mounting the folder /home/parsis/code of my machine to the /notebooks/ folder of jupyter notebook. The problem is that the files I made in the notebook (like .ipynb files) do not show up at the specified directory of my machine. I used the following command to run the container.

```
docker run --gpus all  -it -p 5010:8888 --name parsis  -v /home/parsis/code:/notebooks/ tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.0-gpu-jupyter
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the part I was doing wrong was that I was mapping it to the wrong(maybe nonexistant!) folder in container. I should have mapped it to the folder `/tf/` instead of the folder `/notebooks/`. you can find this folder by going interactive into your container and using a bash command like `ls`